# Удаление ячейки UITableView в определенной секции

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Есть кастомный класс описывающий ячейку и там есть кнопка. Надо чтобы по нажатию на кнопку происходило удаление этой ячейки.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class PurchesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var purchesTableView: UITableView!
    let manage = ManagerData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        purchesTableView.delegate = self
        purchesTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        purchesTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return manage.loadPurchases().0.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return manage.loadPurchases().0[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return manage.loadPurchases().1[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "purchesCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomPurchesTableViewCell

        cell.productLabel.text = manage.loadPurchases().1[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.weightProductLabel.text = manage.loadPurchases().2[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.weightNameLabel.text = manage.loadPurchases().3[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

//        cell.boughtButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeProduct), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
}

class CustomPurchesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var boughtButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var productLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightProductLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func removePurches(_ sender: Any) {
        print("remove")
    }
}
```

метод для получения данных

```
func loadPurchases() -> ([String], Array<Array<String>>, Array<Array<String>>, Array<Array<String>>) {
        var sections: [String] = []
        var product = Array<Array<String>>()
        var weight = Array<Array<String>>()
        var nameWeight = Array<Array<String>>()

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let data = realm.objects(Purches.self)
        for item in data {
            if sections.contains(item.nameDish) == false {
                sections.append(item.nameDish)
            }
        }

        for a in sections {
            var productArr = Array<String>()
            var weightArr = Array<String>()
            var nameWeightArr = Array<String>()
            for prod in data {
                if a == prod.nameDish {
                    productArr.append(prod.product)
                    weightArr.append(prod.weight)
                    nameWeightArr.append(prod.nameWeigh)
                }
            }
            product.append(productArr)
            weight.append(weightArr)
            nameWeight.append(nameWeightArr)
        }
        return (sections, product, weight, nameWeight)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализация списков и таблиц в приложениях бывает трудной и запутанной, однако идея в целом простая: у Вас есть ***контролер*** таблицы, который имеет ***массив*** данных (или несколько, у Вас их вроде 3 шт) и ***ячейки***, которые динамически создаются под каждое значение массива, а также ***вью***, сама таблица. Полноценный ответ в виде кода расписывать долго, а в интернете полно полноценных проектов, поэтому постараюсь дать поясненияющие советы.

Для описанной Вами механики необходимо следующее: каждая ячейка должна знать свой **индекс** в массиве и иметь **ссылку** на объект контроллера. При нажатии на кнопку ячейка обращается по ссылке к контроллеру и передаёт свой индекс затем, чтобы он её удалил и обновил таблицу. И то, и другое нужно передавать в конструкторе при создании ячейки в методе `[ tableView cellForRowAt ]`.

То есть, в контроллере у Вас должен быть метод вроде `delete_row_at_index:(int)ind`, там удаляете соответствующие индексы массива и вызываете метод `reloadData` Вашего объекта `purchesTableView`. После этого он сам обратится к объекту-контроллеру, тот укажет новое количество строк (ведь длина массива была изменена) и затем выдаст нужные ячейки.

**Прочее:**

- Я не совсем понял, используются ли у Вас секции. Если нет, советую поставить `return 1` в методе `numberOfSections`. А если да, то подумайте – возможно всех их проще реализовать на одной ячейке. Чтобы избавиться от конструкций вида `manage.loadPurchases().1[section]`
- Три массива (`purcheses`, `countWeight`, `countNameWeight`) в идеале стоит заменить одним, чтобы использовать словарь или кастомные объект. Изменять размер одного массива проще, чем сразу трёх.

Comment: Спасибо! В самом контроллере я не использую массивы. Секции я использую, от этого не получится отказаться, т.к. название секции является делителем всего списка. Добавил еще метод с помощью которого получаю данные для заполнения. Сами данные храню в REALM

Comment: @Egor Тогда вероятно в ячейки Вам нужно передавать ID позиции из БД. И посмотрите, может число запросов к БД стоит сократить и держать их в переменных, чтобы не выполнять постоянно этот крупный метод. А благодарность на этом сайте выражают стрелкой вверх и галкой принятого ответа `;)`

Comment: ID нету и не планируется, а свои ID он не ведет. Для удаления мне в любом случаем понадобиться 2 значения(название секции и я имя из ячейки)